# How to constrain min and max dates for jQuery-ui datepicker based on another date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, date, jquery-ui-datepicker

I would like to know how can we set the check-out date between the check-in date. Like if we select the month of June (when current month is February) and the 15th day. So it gives the authority to select the day between 30 days(30 limit). So the end date would be: 15 July. Here we have a code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
body{ font: 60.0% "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif; margin: 50px; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#from').datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            firstDay: 1,
            dateFormat: 'DD dd-mm-yy',
            minDate: '0',
            maxDate: '+2Y',
            onSelect: function(dateStr) {
                var min = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                $('#to').datepicker('option', 'minDate', min || '0');
                datepicked();
            } 
        });
        $('#to').datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            firstDay: 1,
            dateFormat: 'DD dd-mm-yy',
            minDate: '0',
            maxDate: '+2Y',
            onSelect: function(dateStr) {
                var max = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                $('#from').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', max || '+2Y');
                datepicked();
            } 
        });
    });
    var datepicked = function() {
        var from = $('#from');
        var to = $('#to');
        var nights = $('#nights');
        var fromDate = from.datepicker('getDate')
        var toDate = to.datepicker('getDate')
        if (toDate && fromDate) {
            var difference = 0;
            var oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
            var difference = Math.ceil((toDate.getTime() - fromDate.getTime()) / oneDay);
            nights.val(difference);
        }
    }
</script>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from" size="28" style="width:194px; /*Tag Style*/" value="" >
<input type="text" id="to" name="to" size="28" style="width:194px; /*Tag Style*/" value="" >
<input type="text" id="nights" name="nights" size="4" style="width:50px; /*Tag Style*/" value="" readonly="readonly">
```

Our Main motive is to make this code, for check-in, check out and nights. In which check-in dates can be any month in 2012-2013, and Check - out date will only be the check-in date after 30 days, and the total nights will be 30 nights only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/zZfCE/7/). I've added some lines in the onSelect event like so:

```
    onSelect: function(dateStr) {
        var d1 = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
        d1.setDate(d1.getDate() + 0); // change to + 1 if necessary
        var d2 = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
        d2.setDate(d2.getDate() + 30); // change to + 29 if necessary
        $("#to").datepicker("setDate", null);
        $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", d1);
        $("#to").datepicker("option", "maxDate", d2);
        datepicked();
    }
```

According to my understanding of lodging business, the dates should be inclusive -- i.e. June/15/2012 + 30 nights should be June/14/2012. But I've followed the example you mentioned in the first few lines of question.

Comment: there is something left, which is related to Check-out date. it should be in between the date of check-in + 30 days. if we select June 28 , the last check -out date will be 28 july. and we can not select the 29 july., but on above example we can easily select the 40 nights ..

Comment: can we do one more thing with this code.like if we load the page, Check-In and Check-out Date will be print on textboxes. check-in date (21/02/2012), and the check-out date will be (22/02/2012). add one day in Check-out date. on page load .

Comment: Add the lines at a suitable location inside document ready function: `$('#from').datepicker("setDate", "0"); $('#to').datepicker("setDate", "+1");` (see [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/zZfCE/8/) here).

Comment: when you change the check in date the check out date goes blank.
This is a mistake. the check out should never go blank, by defect it should always show one day more than the check in and the night should always be 1 .

Comment: It is fairly straight forward. Change the line from `$("#to").datepicker("setDate", null);` to `$("#to").datepicker("setDate", d1);`.