# jQuery calendar match date from previous input

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, calendar, datepicker

So what I am trying to accomplish is what most Hotel or Airport sites have in general, after you've chosen a date for your arrival when clicking on the next calendar it automatically updates the calendar dates to the same month in which you chose your arrival.

See: http://hotelsaxchicago.com

I currently have jQuery UI and it's calendar plugin for a casino/hotel site: http://staging.comanchenationcasinos.com

Is there away to do something similar on here? How can I detect what's already in the input field without actually clicking the submit button.

At the same time, how can I trigger the calendar if someone clicks on the icon instead?

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375265/how-to-constrain-min-and-max-dates-for-jquery-ui-datepicker-based-on-another-dat?

Comment: See http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/ and search for button* for the latter part of your question.

Comment: Thanks Salman. This link you sent me worked great. Didn't know the datepicker was so robust. I got everything I needed from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do for the calendar link next to the input is something like

```
$('body').on('click', '.calendar_icon', function(){
    $(this).prev('input[type="text"]').focus();
    return false;
});
```

That will drop the focus onto the text input sitting previously in the markup.

Regarding the date resetting, try something like this:

Assuming you have the first input with the id of first_date and the second as second_date...

```
$('body').on('change', '#first_date', function(){
    var this_date = $(this).val();
    $('#second_date').datepicker("setDate", new Date(this_date) );
});
```

Worth noting, you could also attach the two date pickers with data-next-datepicker="#something" to make it really specific if you'd rather not use #second_date. I'd go that route if you had a series of dates on the page.

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly for the click function. :)