# Materialize datepicker - Set max date as 30 days from min date selected from another date input box?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, materialize

I want to display the max date as 30 days from the selected start date from another datepicker input box.

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({ 
        selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
        closeOnSelect: true,
        closeOnClear: true,
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        onSet: function (ele) {
           if(ele.select){
                  this.close();
           }

        var d1 = $('#reqstartdate').val();
        var d2 = $('#reqenddate').val();

        var date1 = new Date(d1);
        var date2 = new Date(d2);

},
         min: true,
         max:+30,   
});
```

The above code displays min date as today's date for both date input boxes, and today's date + 30 days as maximum.

Getting dates from textboxes are also included above.

I want the second date to have + 30 days from the input from first date box. 
Is it possible in Materialize datepicker?

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375265/how-to-constrain-min-and-max-dates-for-jquery-ui-datepicker-based-on-another-dat

Comment: @raveenanigam : That answer is for jQuery datepicker. I am using Materialize datepicker.